# Garbage collector error?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I get this error message when the JUnit test executes:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Does the OutOfMemoryError come from an overhead of the garbage collector?

Comment: No. The error is due to GC is too frequent or takes too long during execution. A possible fix is reconfigure the heap, such as enlarging the heap size.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) states clearly: *"Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector"* - so you filled up your heap completely with objects that are still in use

Answer (score 0):

> > Java provides a ***garbage collector*** to automatically look for object's that aren't needed anymore.
> >
> > > All Java objects are stored in your program memory's ***heap***.The heap, which is also referred to as the free store, represents a large pool of unused memory allocated to your Java application.The heap may be quite large, depending on your environment, but there is always a **limit to its size**.If your program keeps instantiating objects and leaving them on the heap, eventually it will run out of memory.